# Django, Use JQuery request a page in div, but how make the page request without other place refresh?

Tags: jquery, html, django

[image]

My page like the pic above. I want click the links in left to manipulate the main area at right.
We know that Frameset and frame is no support in html5, and iframe may be not good. So I want use ajax/jquery to get it.

the page html like this:

```
<div id="left">
    <ul>
        <li onclick="jump('/login/')">link1</li>
        <li onclick="jump('/login/')">link2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="main">{# show page here #}</div>
```

now I can use jquery to open the main right area with login page without refresh the other place

```
function jump(url){
  $("#main").load(url,function(){ $("#main").fadeIn(100);}
);}
```

it works. And the page shows like the picture above.
Now then I want press the login button. Whether login success or not , **the next page still show in the main right area without refresh the other place**.

I want it show like this

[image]

url.py:

```
url(r'^login/$','login',name='login'),
```

login view:

```
def login(request):
    do some login work
    return HttpResponseRedirect(...)  # it can't work,it redirect to absolutely
                                        another page
    return render_to_respose(....)  # it stay at the top-left-right/main page,
                                    but in main div it show nothing, totally blank.
```

How can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just re-render the template on login. You need to either return the HTML needed to replace the area in the page, or you need to return JSON and handle rendering the html needed in the section on the client-side, perhaps via underscore for efficiency.

Either way, you're going to need to handle the replacement of the HTML in question on the client-side. There are many ways to do this... raw JavaScript, jQuery, underscore... it's a pretty broad and highly opinionated question.

Comment: I don't know how to manipulate the frontpage html tag like 'main' in the background view code. Can you sample it please?

Comment: Well, you're going to need to learn :) There are many libraries to help you do this, or just use raw JavaScript, but no one here is going to write all of the code necessary to do what you want; it's just too broad of a question.